# Vim formatting in css

Tags: vimrc, filetype-html, filetype-scss

I am having a very difficult time formatting css in an html file. For example, here is how vim 'thinks' it should be formatted:

[image]

That is, after the above css section, it gives it 8 indentations (??), and doing anything like `=` does the same thing. Here is even a video of that: https://gyazo.com/084317b1746d068d4151c3376c85fa63.

Is there a way to fix this in vim, as it seems almost unusable for doing any html/css/javascript dev (even basic stuff!).

Comment: I just tested with a vimrc containing only `filetype plugin indent on` and I can't reproduce this behavior. I think it would be interesting for you to read [how to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) and edit your question with your findings.